# Why this error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_bin,NONE) for operation '=', ON THIS QUERY?

Tags: mysql, sql, collation, concatenation, mysql-error-1267

Query:

```
select *,
       (@page_path = concat(
           @page_path,
           chk_v_application_tree.alias
       )) as path
from chk_v_application_tree
```

> [Err] 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_bin,NONE) for operation '='

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL case sensitive search for utf8_bin field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901066/mysql-case-sensitive-search-for-utf8-bin-field)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *,
       (@page_path = concat(
           CONVERT(@page_path USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_bin,
           chk_v_application_tree.alias
       )) as path
from chk_v_application_tree
```

As you may not mix charset encoding in an CONCAT function like CONCAT(utf8_general_ci, utf8_bin).